# Divide List<string> into sublists of equal size N

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to slice a List of strings (size N) and return a range based on the list being sliced into equal parts (X).

So for instance, if I have a list of say 10 elements, and my number of tiers is 5.

Elements 0 and 1 are tier 1. Elements 2 and 3 are tier 2. At the end of the method I return the tier specified in the params.

What I'm struggling with is if the list count isn't divisible by the number of tiers. For instance, 23 / 5 = 4.6. So that means they'll be 5 sets of 4, and then 3 left over. I'd like the result to be 5 tiers of 5, 5, 5, 5, 3 (with the final tier just the remaining number of elements).

I've included my code so far, but I'm really stuck on how to ensure the list sizes are as equal as possible and how to handle remainders.

```
// Gets a list and returns a range by the tier specified
public List<string> GetRangeByTierIndex(List<string> listToDivide, int numOfTiers, int tierIndexToGet)
{
    int numOfElementsPerList = listToDivide.Count / numOfTiers;

    int index = (tierToGet - 1) * numOfElementsPerList;

    return listToDivide.GetRange(index, numOfElementsPerList);
}
```

Note: Forgot to mention, I can't use LINQ for this either (AOT and iOS problems).

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned before I can't use LINQ for this.

Comment: there are a few non-linq solutions in there too I believe

Comment: Your first example of 10 element and 5 tiers is 5 sets of 2, but in  your second example of 23 elements and 5 tiers you say that's 4 sets of 5.  Shouldn't it be 5 sets of 4?

Comment: Yep it should be 5 sets of 4 :)

Comment: Why can't you use linq?  Just curious since I'm thinking of a solution that uses iterator blocks but not sure if that would work either.

Comment: Can you just do like this.
int numOfElementsPerList = listToDivide.Count / numberOfTiers;
int remaining = (ListToDivide.Count) - (numOfElementPerList)

?

Comment: I'm developing for iOS and I'm always wary of LINQ and AOT problems on iOS

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use modulo which is remainder of division of `listToDivide.Count` by `numOfTiers`. If that remainder is greater than zero all tiers which index is less or equal to that remainder will have one more element. Because of that, start index of every tier must be corrected also. Note that I haven't wrote any checks (like if number of elements in main list is zero, `numOfTiers < tierIndexToGet`, etc... but you can add those checks if you need). Also, this will, for your example, give lists with `5, 5, 5, 4, 4` elements instead of `5, 5, 5, 5, 3` but I think this is even better. Anyway I hope it will be good for your needs. Code should look something like:

```
public List<string> GetRangeByTierIndex(List<string> listToDivide, int numOfTiers, int tierIndexToGet)
{
    int remaining = listToDivide.Count % numOfTiers;
    int numOfElementsPerList = listToDivide.Count / numOfTiers;
    int index = (tierIndexToGet - 1) * numOfElementsPerList;
    if (remaining > 0)
    {
        // most increase position of index because of numOfElementsPerList correction bellow
        index += tierIndexToGet > remaining ? remaining : tierIndexToGet - 1;
        // first 'remaining-th' tiers will have +1 element
        numOfElementsPerList += tierIndexToGet <= remaining ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return listToDivide.GetRange(index, numOfElementsPerList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: 23 and 5.

- 23/5 = 4 // 4 tiers of 5 - use integer division
- 23%5 = 3 // 1 tier of 3

Comment: The problem with this solution is, if you have 21 elements in main list, number of elements in tiers would be 5,5,5,5,1. My example gives 5, 4, 4, 4, 4 which is better distribution